# C compiler cannot create executables when trying to install ruby-1.9.3-p392 on Yosemite OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

I recently upgraded my OSX to Yosemite.
As a result i needed to remove and install the ruby versions on my computer. 
When i am trying to install ruby 1.9.3-p392 i am getting an error :

```
~$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p392, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9789k  100 9789k    0     0   479k      0  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:-- 1987k
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p392 to /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392....
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #applying patch /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/patches/ruby/GH-488.patch.
ruby-1.9.3-p392 - #configuring.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/log/1415518177_ruby-1.9.3-p392/configure.log
[2014-11-09 09:29:45] ./configure
current path: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392
GEM_HOME=/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4
PATH=/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/bin:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Applications/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql-5.1.58-osx10.6-x86_64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/bin:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4:/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

This is the config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure --prefix=/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = LitalZ.local
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 14.0.0
uname -s = Darwin
uname -v = Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = Mach kernel version:
     Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 19 00:26:44 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2782.1.97~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel configured for up to 4 processors.
2 processors are physically available.
4 processors are logically available.
Processor type: x86_64h (Intel x86-64h Haswell)
Processors active: 0 1 2 3
Primary memory available: 4.00 gigabytes
Default processor set: 243 tasks, 1028 threads, 4 processors
Load average: 1.71, Mach factor: 2.29
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/libtool/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/automake/bin
PATH: /usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin
PATH: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin
PATH: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@global/bin
PATH: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /Applications/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin
PATH: /usr/local/heroku/bin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /opt/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /opt/local/bin
PATH: /usr/local/mysql-5.1.58-osx10.6-x86_64/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/bin
PATH: /Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2792: checking build system type
configure:2806: result: i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
configure:2874: checking host system type
configure:2887: result: i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
configure:2907: checking target system type
configure:2920: result: i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
configure:3401: checking for C compiler version
configure:3410: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 --version >&5
./configure: line 3412: 42359 Segmentation fault: 11  $CC --version 1>&5
configure:3421: $? = 139
configure:3410: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -v >&5
./configure: line 3412: 42364 Segmentation fault: 11  $CC -v 1>&5
configure:3421: $? = 139
configure:3410: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -V >&5
./configure: line 3412: 42371 Segmentation fault: 11  $CC -V 1>&5
configure:3421: $? = 139
configure:3410: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6 -qversion >&5
./configure: line 3412: 42376 Segmentation fault: 11  $CC -qversion 1>&5
configure:3421: $? = 139
configure:3441: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3463: /usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6    conftest.c  >&5
./configure: line 3465: 42386 Segmentation fault: 11  $CC $CFLAGS $CPPFLAGS $LDFLAGS conftest.$ac_ext $LIBS 1>&5
configure:3467: $? = 139
configure:3505: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3510: error: in `/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p392':
configure:3512: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=i386-apple-darwin14.0.0
ac_cv_prog_CC=/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6
ac_cv_target=i386-apple-darwin14.0.0

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ALLOCA=''
AR=''
ARCHFILE=''
ARCH_FLAG=''
AS=''
ASFLAGS=''
BASERUBY='ruby'
BUILTIN_ENCOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSOBJS=''
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS=''
CAPITARGET=''
CC='/usr/local/opt/gcc46/bin/gcc-4.6'
CCDLFLAGS=''
CFLAGS=''
CHDIR=''
COMMON_HEADERS=''
COMMON_LIBS=''
COMMON_MACROS=''
COUTFLAG=''
CP=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPOUTFILE=''
CXX=''
CXXFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
DLDFLAGS=''
DLDLIBS=''
DLEXT2=''
DLEXT=''
DLLWRAP=''
DOT=''
DOXYGEN=''
ECHO_C='\c'
ECHO_N=''
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
ENABLE_SHARED=''
EXECUTABLE_EXTS=''
EXEEXT=''
EXPORT_PREFIX=''
EXTOUT=''
EXTSTATIC=''
GCC=''
GNU_LD=''
GREP=''
INSTALLDOC=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDSHARED=''
LDSHAREDXX=''
LIBEXT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBPATHENV=''
LIBPATHFLAG=''
LIBRUBY=''
LIBRUBYARG=''
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED=''
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC=''
LIBRUBY_A=''
LIBRUBY_ALIASES=''
LIBRUBY_DLDFLAGS=''
LIBRUBY_LDSHARED=''
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE=''
LIBRUBY_SO=''
LIBS=''
LINK_SO=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINLIBS=''
MAJOR='1'
MAKEDIRS=''
MAKEFILES=''
MANTYPE=''
MINIOBJS=''
MINIRUBY=''
MINOR='9'
MKDIR_P=''
NM=''
NROFF=''
NULLCMD=''
OBJCOPY=''
OBJDUMP=''
OBJEXT=''
OUTFLAG=''
PACKAGE=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PKG_CONFIG=''
PLATFORM_DIR=''
PREP=''
RANLIB=''
RDOCTARGET=''
RI_BASE_NAME=''
RM=''
RMALL=''
RMDIR=''
RMDIRS=''
RPATHFLAG=''
RUBYW_BASE_NAME='rubyw'
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_BASE_NAME='ruby'
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME=''
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION='1.9.3'
RUBY_RELEASE_DATE='2013-02-22'
RUBY_SO_NAME=''
RUNRUBY=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SOLIBS=''
STATIC=''
STRIP=''
SYMBOL_PREFIX=''
TEENY='1'
TEST_RUNNABLE=''
THREAD_MODEL=''
TRY_LINK=''
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES=''
UNIVERSAL_INTS=''
USE_RUBYGEMS=''
WERRORFLAG=''
WINDRES=''
XCFLAGS=''
XLDFLAGS=''
XRUBY=''
XRUBY_LIBDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYHDRDIR=''
XRUBY_RUBYLIBDIR=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_OBJCOPY=''
ac_ct_OBJDUMP=''
arch=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='i386-apple-darwin14.0.0'
build_alias=''
build_cpu='i386'
build_os='darwin14.0.0'
build_vendor='apple'
cflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
configure_args=''
cppflags=''
cxxflags=' ${optflags} ${debugflags} ${warnflags}'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
debugflags=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='i386-apple-darwin14.0.0'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='i386'
host_os='darwin14.0.0'
host_vendor='apple'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
optflags=''
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/Users/lital.zubery/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392'
program_transform_name='s&^&&'
psdir='${docdir}'
ridir=''
ruby_pc=''
ruby_version=''
rubyhdrdir=''
rubylibprefix=''
rubyw_install_name=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
setup=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sitearch=''
sitedir=''
sitehdrdir=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target='i386-apple-darwin14.0.0'
target_alias=''
target_cpu='i386'
target_os='darwin14.0.0'
target_vendor='apple'
try_header=''
vendordir=''
vendorhdrdir=''
warnflags=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define CANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN 1

configure: exit 77
```

I have tried to reinstall the rvm - didn't help that match. 
I have tried to update the XCode and also reinstall it. didn't help also. 
I'd love for some help please ..

P.S.
I am able to install other versions of ruby through RVM .

Comment: Well I have fixed it by removing all gcc that were installed on my mac and install onlt gcc48 (brew install). After that - installing ruby with RVM worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the latest XCode and XCode terminal utilities. It is required to compile ruby on osx 10.10